# using PHP variable within onClick

Tags: php, javascript, onclick

I was wondering what is wrong with this  tag I am using which uses a PHP variable within an onClick event.

after looking around for other answers on this i have tried to do it but for some reason it doesnt work.

```
<a onclick="setCartDisplay('<?=$prodID;?>'); return false;" href="prodtest2.php?action=add&id=<?=$id;?>">
```

Here is the code leading up to and including the link tag that doesnt work.

```
$prod_query = 'SELECT * FROM *****.*****';
        $prod_details = db_query_into_array_enhanced($mysql_connection, $prod_query);                       
        $count = count($prod_details);
        for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) 
            {?>     
            <?  $prodID = $prod_details[$i]['catID'];
                $prodDesc = $prod_details[$i]['shortDescription'];
                $prodPrice = $prod_details[$i]['rrp'];
            ?>
             <tr>
                 <td><?=$prodID;?></td>
                 <td><?=$prodDesc;?></td>
                 <td><?=$prodPrice;?></td>
                 <td><a onclick="setCartDisplay('<?=$prodID;?>'); return false;" href="prodtest2.php?action=add&id=<?=$prodID;?>">Add To Cart</a></td>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `it doesn't work`? What are the errors in the console?

Comment: do you have short php tags enabled in your php.ini?

Comment: Keep in mind that PHP is executed on the server, before any output (including your Javascript) is sent to the browser. Check your HTML source before executing the `onclick` event: is the correct value of `$prodID` present?

Comment: @VisioN there are no errors, the link just doesnt do anything or go anywhere. nothing happens. Fabio -  yes short PHP tags is enabled and working correctly. George Cummins -  yeah $prodID does have the correct value in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better solution is to store the `id` from php, as the id of the anchor element and retrieve it after using javascript.

As of html 5 any characters are valid for an id (and as it is a product ID I am guessing there will not be duplicates, if there are simply add it as a class instead with a prefix). This way would also require you to have a class on the anchors.

This gets around you having to set the onclick of the `a` tag, which in my eyes is always a bad idea as it mixes your html with javascript, and imagine if you had a 1000 of these links on your page and the function name changed, you can start to see why it becomes a better solution;

The html;

```
<a id="<?= $prodID; ?>" class="product" href="prodtest2.php?action=add&id=<?= $id; ?>">
```

And the javascript (Jquery)

```
$(".product").click(function() {
     var id = $(this).attr("id");
     setCartDisplay(id);
});
```

The reason your link is not working in the first place is because you are returning false from your function call which disables the default behaviour of the click event.